# What could be wrong on my car

Tags: tires, wheels, holden, captiva

[image]My wheel is on an angle After a small accident. What could I have broken

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What is the year of your car?

Answer (score 3):

Could be tie rod, control arm lower ball joint, axle. This is unsafe to drive. It needs to be towed to your mechanic.

Comment: Very lucky if only one component is damaged.

Comment: @ToniHoffensetz, if you are extremely lucky your wheel has been knocked out of alignment without any other damage, but I agree you definitely shouldn't drive it. A) you could make the damage worse and have a more expensive repair and B) the suspension could fail while you are driving and cause a serious accident with you in it. Get a tow.

Comment: It could be *limped* to the mechanic.  Keep it under 15 mph and keep both hands on the wheel. The problem with going faster is kinetic energy is the square of speed, so if you're moving twice the speed, you have *half the time* to arrest *4 times the kinetic energy* before you hit something. You might be suddenly thrown off course if something breaks.